# Where do I find libboost_random?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, boost, random, linker

I'm trying to compile websocket++ which by default compiles as static. I thought that the shared option would be best so I did a:

```
make SHARED-1
```

I get various outputs with the following error (ignoring the ones that I think are caused by the following error):

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_random
```

I've searched and searched and cannot find anyone else who has had the same problem, not with websocket++ but with using the random boost library.

I eventually found out how to check my version via:

```
apt-cache showpkg libboost-all-dev
```

This states that I have:

```
1.48.0.2 (/var/lib/apt/lists/mirror.aarnet.edu.au_pub_ubuntu_archive_dists_precise_universe_binary-amd64_Packages)
```

Btw, I'm on Ubuntu 12.04.

I checked the version because I've seen comments on posts regarding 1.46 (which I think was what 11.10 supported).

If I do an:

```
ls /usr/lib/libboost_*.so
```

I get:

```
/usr/lib/libboost_date_time-mt.so        /usr/lib/libboost_serialization-mt.so  
/usr/lib/libboost_thread-mt.so           /usr/lib/libboost_date_time.so
/usr/lib/libboost_serialization.so       /usr/lib/libboost_thread.so
/usr/lib/libboost_program_options-mt.so  /usr/lib/libboost_signals-mt.so
/usr/lib/libboost_wserialization-mt.so   /usr/lib/libboost_program_options.so
/usr/lib/libboost_signals.so             /usr/lib/libboost_wserialization.so
/usr/lib/libboost_regex-mt.so            /usr/lib/libboost_system-mt.so
/usr/lib/libboost_regex.so               /usr/lib/libboost_system.so
```

So obviously the libraries are installed, I just see no boost_random.

I suspect that maybe random has been removed from boost into a standard c++ lib? I wasn't sure but I have seen some comments to the effect that this has happened to other areas. Problem is I would have thought I would see some posts somewhere on the net if this is the case.

I should note that the author of libwebsocket++ state that 1.47 boost is tested on osx, 1.46 is tested on linux. So I suspect it's a versioning issue with the libs. Just hoping someone can provide some guidance as to what I need to fix to correct the problem.

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strange. I am running 12.04 and I am currently using boost::random as well.

I have a LOT more boost libraries installed that you do. Looking back at my dpkg log I can see that I installed `libboost-dev`. This installed 1.48.0.2 on my machine. Try this and report back.

```
$ ls /usr/lib/libboost_*.so
/usr/lib/libboost_chrono-mt.so          /usr/lib/libboost_iostreams.so     /usr/lib/libboost_math_tr1l-mt.so        /usr/lib/libboost_prg_exec_monitor-mt.so  /usr/lib/libboost_regex-mt.so          /usr/lib/libboost_timer.so
/usr/lib/libboost_chrono.so             /usr/lib/libboost_locale-mt.so     /usr/lib/libboost_math_tr1l.so           /usr/lib/libboost_prg_exec_monitor.so     /usr/lib/libboost_regex.so             /usr/lib/libboost_unit_test_framework-mt.so
/usr/lib/libboost_date_time-mt.so       /usr/lib/libboost_locale.so        /usr/lib/libboost_math_tr1-mt.so         /usr/lib/libboost_program_options-mt.so   /usr/lib/libboost_serialization-mt.so  /usr/lib/libboost_unit_test_framework.so
/usr/lib/libboost_date_time.so          /usr/lib/libboost_math_c99f-mt.so  /usr/lib/libboost_math_tr1.so            /usr/lib/libboost_program_options.so      /usr/lib/libboost_serialization.so     /usr/lib/libboost_wave-mt.so
/usr/lib/libboost_filesystem-mt.so      /usr/lib/libboost_math_c99f.so     /usr/lib/libboost_mpi-mt.so              /usr/lib/libboost_python-mt-py27.so       /usr/lib/libboost_signals-mt.so        /usr/lib/libboost_wave.so
/usr/lib/libboost_filesystem.so         /usr/lib/libboost_math_c99l-mt.so  /usr/lib/libboost_mpi_python-mt-py27.so  /usr/lib/libboost_python-mt-py32.so       /usr/lib/libboost_signals.so           /usr/lib/libboost_wserialization-mt.so
/usr/lib/libboost_graph-mt.so           /usr/lib/libboost_math_c99l.so     /usr/lib/libboost_mpi_python-mt-py32.so  /usr/lib/libboost_python-py27.so          /usr/lib/libboost_system-mt.so         /usr/lib/libboost_wserialization.so
/usr/lib/libboost_graph_parallel-mt.so  /usr/lib/libboost_math_c99-mt.so   /usr/lib/libboost_mpi_python-py27.so     /usr/lib/libboost_python-py32.so          /usr/lib/libboost_system.so
/usr/lib/libboost_graph_parallel.so     /usr/lib/libboost_math_c99.so      /usr/lib/libboost_mpi_python-py32.so     /usr/lib/libboost_python.so               /usr/lib/libboost_thread-mt.so
/usr/lib/libboost_graph.so              /usr/lib/libboost_math_tr1f-mt.so  /usr/lib/libboost_mpi_python.so          /usr/lib/libboost_random-mt.so            /usr/lib/libboost_thread.so
/usr/lib/libboost_iostreams-mt.so       /usr/lib/libboost_math_tr1f.so     /usr/lib/libboost_mpi.so                 /usr/lib/libboost_random.so               /usr/lib/libboost_timer-mt.so
```

You can also install it directly. e.g.

```
$ apt-cache search boost random
libboost-random-dev - Boost Random Number Library (default version)
libboost-random1.46-dev - Boost Random Number Library
libboost-random1.46.1 - Boost Random Number Library
libboost-random1.48-dev - Boost Random Number Library
libboost-random1.48.0 - Boost Random Number Library

$sudo apt-get install libboost-random1.46-dev
```

or whatever version you want.

Comment: Hmm... installed 45.2 MB of libs, but no libboost_random.so or libboost_random-mt.so. I do have new libs, just not random. Very strange... 

Missed your last comment on how to install, I'll try manually now.

Comment: Very strange, I tried libboost-random1.48.0 and it said that it installed it. But it's not in /usr/lib. whereis doesn't find it. It said it was setting up libboost-random1.48.0 (1.48.0-3), doesn't say where too.

Did a find and I think I found it. It's in /usr/lib after all, but it's called libboost_random.so.1.48.0. My mask when doing an ls was libboost_*.so, so I couldn't see it. Should I rename it or do a symlink on it? Seems kinda useless as is without changing the Makefile (which I would rather avoid).

Comment: I did a `$dpkg -l | grep boost` and there is a `libboost1.48-all-dev` and a `libboost1.48-dev`. Try the "all" version.

Comment: d'oh! I've made the same mistake. I use `find /usr/lib -name "libboost*"` to make sure my search is greedy.  Don't make links, they should already be there. e.g. `/usr/lib/libboost_random.so -> libboost_random.so.1.48.0`

Comment: Sorry Mr Stinky, but I'm not seeing the `libboost1.48-alldev` or the `libboost`.48-dev`, all I can see is `libboost-all-dev` which is listed as 1.48.02, which I installed AFAICT.

I just have the `/usr/lib/libboost_random.so.1.48.0`, no links were created for me...

Comment: Just link with `-lboost_random` and it will pick up the library - unless you want to link to a specific version of Boost.

Comment: The makefile is doing that. It has a `-lboost_random` but it doesn't pick it up. Hence the error `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_random`. O.o

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16245/discussion-between-mr-stinky-and-metalskin)

Comment: As per chat, changed makefile to refer to the actual file, but no go. Created a symbolic link manually to the correct file and it fixes the problem. Not sure still why I couldn't the file, but I reckon this is solved. thanks for your help.